# pyspark create n columns based on selecting column values from other rows in the same group

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to add n columns to the each row of the data frame  based on below  conditions
1)apply group by operation with given group by columns
2)process each group 
3)for each record in the group select last n values of a column from other records based on given criteria

**dataframe :**

```
   demo,origin,gap,date_nor,date,ratings
   men_20_21, india, -1, 0, 1/11/2020,0.1
   men_20_21, india, 0, 1, 2/11/2020,0.2
   men_20_21, india, 1, 2, 3/11/2020,0.3
   men_20_21, india, 2, 3, 4/11/2020,0.4
   men_20_21, india, 3, 4, 5/11/2020,0.5
   men_30_35, india, 4, 5, 6/11/2020,0.6
   men_30_35, india, 5, 6, 7/11/2020,0.7
   men_30_35, india, 6, 7, 8/11/2020,0.8
   men_30_35, india, 7, 8, 9/11/2020,0.9
   men_30_35, india, 8, 9, 10/11/2020,0.10
   men_30_35, india, 9, 10, 11/11/2020,0.11
   men_30_35, india, 10, 11, 12/11/2020,0.12
```

**above data frame is grouped by columns demo and origin**

**output dataframe**

```
   demo,origin,gap,date_nor,date,ratings,1last_rating,2last_rating,3last_rating,4last_rating,5last_rating
   men_20_21, india, -1, 0, 1/11/2020,0.1,null,null,null,null,null
   men_20_21, india, 0, 1, 2/11/2020,0.2,0.1,null,null,null,null
   men_20_21, india, 1, 2, 3/11/2020,0.3,0.2,.0.1,null,null,null
   men_20_21, india, 2, 3, 4/11/2020,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,null,null
   men_20_21, india, 3, 4, 5/11/2020,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,null
   men_30_35, india, 4, 5, 6/11/2020,0.6,null,null,null,null,null
   men_30_35, india, 5, 6, 7/11/2020,0.7,0.6,null,null,null,null
   men_30_35, india, 6, 7, 8/11/2020,0.8,0.7,0.6,null,null,null
   men_30_35, india, 7, 8, 9/11/2020,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,null,null
   men_30_35, india, 8, 9, 10/11/2020,0.10,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,null
   men_30_35, india, 9, 10, 11/11/2020,0.11,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6
   men_30_35, india, 10, 11, 12/11/2020,0.12,0.11,0.10,0.9,0.8,0.7
```

**Explanation**

for each row select last 5[here n=5] values of ratings column when gap>=date_nor ,if no row satisfies condition update with null value for all the last 5 values. If number of rows satifies the condition less than 5 update corresponding last values with null.

I loaded input data like below and did a group by, but not getting idea on how to proceed.**

```
df=spark.read.csv("D:\\input\file1.csv")
df=df.groupby(["demo","origin"])
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using window functions i'm able to solve the problem

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
df=spark.sql("select *, lag(ratings, 1, null) over (partition by demo, origin order by date_nor) as 1_last_rating,lag(ratings, 2, null) over (partition by demo, origin order by date_nor) as 2_last_rating,lag(ratings, 3, null) over (partition by demo, origin order by date_nor) as 3_last_rating,lag(ratings, 4, null) over (partition by demo, origin order by date_nor) as 4_last_rating,lag(ratings, 5, null) over (partition by demo, origin order by date_nor) as 5_last_rating from df")
df.show()
```

```
+---------+------+----+--------+-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|     demo|origin| gap|date_nor|       date|ratings|1_last_rating|2_last_rating|3_last_rating|4_last_rating|5_last_rating|
+---------+------+----+--------+-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|men_20_21| india|-1.0|     0.0| 01/11/2020|    0.1|         null|         null|         null|         null|         null|
|men_20_21| india| 0.0|     1.0| 02/11/2020|    0.2|          0.1|         null|         null|         null|         null|
|men_20_21| india| 1.0|     2.0| 03/11/2020|    0.3|          0.2|          0.1|         null|         null|         null|
|men_20_21| india| 2.0|     3.0| 04/11/2020|    0.4|          0.3|          0.2|          0.1|         null|         null|
|men_20_21| india| 3.0|     4.0| 05/11/2020|    0.5|          0.4|          0.3|          0.2|          0.1|         null|
|men_30_35| india| 4.0|     5.0| 06/11/2020|    0.6|         null|         null|         null|         null|         null|
|men_30_35| india| 5.0|     6.0| 07/11/2020|    0.7|          0.6|         null|         null|         null|         null|
|men_30_35| india| 6.0|     7.0| 08/11/2020|    0.8|          0.7|          0.6|         null|         null|         null|
|men_30_35| india| 7.0|     8.0| 09/11/2020|    0.9|          0.8|          0.7|          0.6|         null|         null|
|men_30_35| india| 8.0|     9.0| 10/11/2020|    0.1|          0.9|          0.8|          0.7|          0.6|         null|
|men_30_35| india| 9.0|    10.0| 11/11/2020|   0.11|          0.1|          0.9|          0.8|          0.7|          0.6|
|men_30_35| india|10.0|    11.0| 12/11/2020|   0.12|         0.11|          0.1|          0.9|          0.8|          0.7|
+---------+------+----+--------+-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. However, it should be noted that this will always take the last 5 values, regardless of the date. If one wanted to have the last 5 *days* for example, the query needs to be slightly modified.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking to create bunch of dynamic columns based on some business conditions.

Perhaps you can leverage 'withColumn' function, like

> df.withColumn('last_rating_1', regex_replace(col('date_nor')...)